# Using the WLLN for deriving an OLS estimator

Tags: least-squares, law-of-large-numbers

I am reading an introductory econometrics book and I am having trouble understanding how they "directly applied the law of large numbers".
Basically, they consider the case of simple linear regression model, trying to show how it behaves asymptotically.

they begin just with the formula of the slope parameter estimator like this:

[image]

and then only say that they "apply the law of large numbers" to it and somehow get:

[image]

I was only taught the basic relationship regarding the LLN which is that in a limit, as n goes to infinity, the sample average should converge to the true mean of the distribution. I have no idea how to use it in this case when there is the square or that another term u in the sum. Can someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: It's still a sample average, even if it's the sample average of a squared term or of a cross product!

Comment: I just looked up the law of large numbers again and now I am even more confused. In all the formulas, there is the true parameter, or the true expected value of the distribution. In the example I posted, the author uses just the average calculated from the given sample, which doesnt even make sense since the sum o differences of the values in  a sample and its average will be zero.

Comment: Not squared they won't, and not multiplied by something they are correlated with they won't.  $(1/n)\Sigma x_i^2$ converges to $\mathbb{E}x^2$, not to $0$, even when the true mean equals $0$.

Comment: Oh, sure, this reminds me of the method of moments - the case you mentioned is the one for the second theoretical and sample moment. There is an equallity so what you wrote holds. However, I wasnt able to "prove" (or find the proof) that just from knowing this for the first moment (1. power).

Comment: Reread my first comment... $(1/n)\Sigma x_i^2$ is the sample average of the $x_i^2$.   Define $y_i = x_i^2$; the first moment of the $y_i$ is the same as the second (noncentral) moment of the $x_i$.   Since $\bar{y}$ converges, obviously $\bar{x^2}$ does as well.

Comment: All clear now, thank you.